# Mint Linux - Calling update-initramfs from a mounted partition

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mount, kvm, initramfs

I'm kind of a newbie to linux. I'm having trouble installing a mint linux on a KVM while passing a nvidia graphics card. The first problem I'm having is the known issue `"Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed"` and the second one is that it freezes right after the message is shown(might be the same problem) while booting.

For the first problem I've found that updating the `initramfs` would do the trick, but as I could not access the installed mint version I had to open the installation disk's mint with compatibility mode. There I mounted without binding(can't bind, shows error) the installed partition, changed the `initramfs.conf` with the suggested fix and now I just have to run `update-initramfs -u` to apply the change but I cant figure out how to call it once the partition is not bound. Anyone knows how can I call the command in this scenario?

Would this also fix the freezing at boot? If not, any suggestions?

Comment: did you found solution?

Comment: no, I installed kubuntu :/